# MongoDb listener in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, listener

I want to listen to new records in a MongoDb collection based on a condition and send them to clients via Socket.Io

As I see it should look something like this:

```
var lastTime = Date.now();
while(true) {
    getRecordsLaterThan(lastTime, function(results) {
        if (results) {
            for (let result of results) {
                lastTime = result.created_on;
                // send result via Socket.Io
            }
        }
    });
    // sleep(200 ms)
}
```

I'm quite new to Node and JS and still sometimes have hard time understanding it's execution flow. In this case a can't figure out how to make the loop sleep after each iteration.

Also I have doubts that perhaps with Node it should be done in a completely different way.

Comment: Check out this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-watch

Comment: @JAM thanks, but I believe it doesn't fit my requirements. I need to listen the collection with specific query conditions and I can't see how it can be done with this lib.

Comment: I think it could work for your scenario. Instead of polling (like you do now, each 200 milliseconds), you could do a query when the database changes (by utilizing mongo-watch) - then decide if you need to broadcast the result with socket.io. This would be an eventbased solution, as well as relieving stress off your database & server.

Comment: @JAM makes sense, thanks! Will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading I think I found how it should be done in a Node-specific way using recursion and setTimeout:

```
var lastTime = Date.now();

function listen() {
    getRecordsLaterThan(lastTime, function(results) {
        if (results) {
            for (let result of results) {
                lastTime = result.created_on;
                // send result via Socket.Io
            }
        }
    });
    setTimeout(listen, 200);
}

listen();
```